# How does Eclipse MemoryAnalyzer work?

Tags: android, eclipse, heap-memory, ddms

I'm trying to find a String from an Android app's heap dump I grabbed from Eclipse's DDMS. I converted the file using the SDK's hprof-conv. Now if I open the file in the Eclipse MemoryAnalyzer it gives me a list of Strings that are in the heap which is great! I find exactly what I need. However, I'm trying to write a script that will grab the String I'm looking for from the heap dump. The problem I'm having is that I'm not seeing this String when I'm running Strings on the dump or running the dump through a hex editor. I don't understand where MemoryAnalyzer is getting the Strings I'm looking for. Anyone have any idea what's going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Java is using [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) character encoding for Strings internally. So you might need to search for your search term in that encoding, if using a hex editor on the dump.